# XText : ML_COMMENT overrides own written comment

Tags: xtext, xtend

I am new to xtext.

I want to add the following comments.

1. ML_COMMENT (from org.eclipse.xtext.common.Terminals)
2. own comment

   /*
      @var var1 
      @property property1
   */

The following is my attempt code.

```
grammar org.xtext.example.mydemo.MyDemo with org.eclipse.xtext.common.Terminals

generate myDemo "http://www.xtext.org/example/mydemo/MyDemo"

Model:
   (elements+=DocComments)*
;

DocComments hidden(WS, OTHER):
   start=StartComment name=VarComment? property=PropertyComment* end=EndComment
;

StartComment: '/**';
EndComment:'*/';
VarComment: key='@var' name=ID;
PropertyComment: key='@property' name=ID;

terminal OTHER: '*';
```

It seems that ML_COMMENT works and own comment does not work.

How to resolve this problem?
Please help.

Comment: Just as a side note: your StartComment is /** not /* which means that  you are matching against "/** ... */"

Answer (score 0):

you can override `ML_COMMENT` to something "else"

e.g.

```
ML_COMMENT: '%'->'%';
```

or you dont inherit from terminals but copy the rules (except `ML_COMMENT`)

```
grammar org.xtext.example.demodsl.DemoDsl hidden(WS, SL_COMMENT)

generate demoDsl "http://www.xtext.org/example/demodsl/DemoDsl"

import "http://www.eclipse.org/emf/2002/Ecore" as ecore
Model:
    greetings+=Greeting*;

Greeting:
    'Hello' name=ID '!';


terminal ID         : '^'?('a'..'z'|'A'..'Z'|'_') ('a'..'z'|'A'..'Z'|'_'|'0'..'9')*;
terminal INT returns ecore::EInt: ('0'..'9')+;
terminal STRING : 
            '"' ( '\\' . /* 'b'|'t'|'n'|'f'|'r'|'u'|'"'|"'"|'\\' */ | !('\\'|'"') )* '"' |
            "'" ( '\\' . /* 'b'|'t'|'n'|'f'|'r'|'u'|'"'|"'"|'\\' */ | !('\\'|"'") )* "'"
        ; 
terminal SL_COMMENT     : '//' !('\n'|'\r')* ('\r'? '\n')?;

terminal WS         : (' '|'\t'|'\r'|'\n')+;

terminal ANY_OTHER: .;
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply.

Comment: I  tried adding the following in code.
terminal ML_COMMENT: '%'->'%'; 
Then own comment works. 

But I want to add both "own comment" and "ML_COMMENT".
for example:
/**
  *@var var1
  *@property property1
  *@property property2
 */


 /* multiple comment may by anything */


/*
  * multiple comment
  */

Comment: This is not possible you have to handle this in your rule

Comment: Can you elaborate more on your usecase

Comment: You may play around with http://xtextcasts.org/episodes/18-model-optimization (the latest xtext workflow does not support postprocessor _> you need manual metsmodel or uncalled ruled)